# else part not displaying content from php

Tags: php, html

```
<?php
$regs=$_GET["regs"];
$schm=$_GET["schm"];

//echo $regs;

$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("adjpoly", $con);

$sql="SELECT * FROM student WHERE Register = '".$regs."'";

//echo $sql;

$result = mysql_query($sql);


$sql1="SELECT `Semester`,`Subject`,`Internal`,`External`,`Total`,`Result`,`Arrear` FROM semester".$schm." where Register ='".$regs."'";

//echo $sql1;
$result1 = mysql_query($sql1);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    if($row==NULL)
    {
        echo '<b style="background-color:#000000">Invalid Number.</b>';
    }
    else
    {
echo "<table style='border:1px solid black;border-collapse:collapse;' width='70%'>
<tr><td style='border:1px solid black;font-weight:bold;background-color:#E2E2E2;font:Tahoma; font-size:13pt' align='right' width='20%'>Name</td>
<td style='border:1px solid black;font-weight:bold;color:#0000CC;background-color:#E2E2E2;font:Tahoma; font-size:13pt'>" . $row['Name']."(". $row['Register']. ")"."</td>
</tr>
<tr><td style='border:1px solid black;font-weight:bold;background-color:#E2E2E2;font:Tahoma; font-size:13pt' align='right' width='20%'>Institution Code</td>
 <td style='border:1px solid black;font-weight:bold;color:#0000CC;background-color:#E2E2E2;font:Tahoma; font-size:13pt'>" . $row['Icode'] . "</td>
</tr>
<tr><td style='border:1px solid black;font-weight:bold;background-color:#E2E2E2;font:Tahoma; font-size:13pt' align='right' width='20%'>Course</td>
<td style='border:1px solid black;font-weight:bold;color:#0000CC;background-color:#E2E2E2;font:Tahoma; font-size:13pt'>" . $row['Course'] ."(FULLTIME)"."(". $row['CCode']. ")". "</td>
</tr>
<tr><td style='border:1px solid black;font-weight:bold;background-color:#E2E2E2;font:Tahoma; font-size:13pt' align='right' width='20%'>Scheme</td>
 <td style='border:1px solid black;font-weight:bold;color:#0000CC;background-color:#E2E2E2;font:Tahoma; font-size:13pt'>" . $row['Scheme'] . "</td>
</tr>";
echo "</table>";

echo "<B> Result : P - Pass   F - Fail   A - Absent </B>";
echo "<table style='border:1px solid black;border-collapse:collapse;' width='70%'>
<tr>
<th style='background-color:#0099CC;color:white;font-size:14pt'>Semester</th>
<th style='background-color:#0099CC;color:white;font-size:14pt'>Subject</th>
<th style='background-color:#0099CC;color:white;font-size:14pt'>Internal Mark</th>
<th style='background-color:#0099CC;color:white;font-size:14pt'>External Mark</th>
<th style='background-color:#0099CC;color:white;font-size:14pt'>Total Mark</th>
<th style='background-color:#0099CC;color:white;font-size:14pt'>Result</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1))
  {
  echo "<tr align='center'>";
  echo "<td bgcolor='#E2E2E2' style='border: 1px solid black;font:Tahoma; font-size:14pt'>" . $row['Semester'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td bgcolor='#E2E2E2' style='border: 1px solid black;font:Tahoma; font-size:14pt'>" . $row['Subject'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td bgcolor='#E2E2E2' style='border: 1px solid black;font:Tahoma; font-size:14pt'>" . $row['Internal'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td bgcolor='#E2E2E2' style='border: 1px solid black;font:Tahoma; font-size:14pt'>" . $row['External'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td bgcolor='#E2E2E2' style='border: 1px solid black;font:Tahoma; font-size:14pt'>" . $row['Total'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td bgcolor='#E2E2E2' style='border: 1px solid black;font:Tahoma; font-size:14pt'>" . $row['Result'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
    $arr = $row['Arrear'];
  }
  echo "<tr align='center' bgcolor='#E2E2E2'><td width='100%' colspan='6' style='border: 1px solid black;'>&nbsp;</td></tr>";
  echo "<tr align='center' bgcolor='#D7DFE3'><td width='100%' align='center' colspan='6' style='border: 1px solid black;'>Arrear:" .$arr . "</td></tr>";
  echo "</table>"; 
    }
}
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

The above php code hav wriiten for displaying the  content retrive from mysql database based on user input.

By using if statement, am validating the given input is present in table. syntax based on below example.

```
if($row==NULL)
{
  echo "Invalid Input.";  // while run, the echo statement not displaying.
}
else
{
o/p part..   //while run, response proper o/p
}
```

can anyone help me. pls

Comment: The `while($row=` is masks the `if($row==NULL)` else part. So the code won't reach the else. -- Also, database escaping. Or prepared statements if you're clever.

Comment: while() will only be executed if the row is equal to true so it can't be null.

Comment: thnks. have any other way to convey my else part msg to user.?

Comment: Maybe use `mysql_num_rows` to check if were found some rows?

Answer (score 0):

I got the correct output. thank u so much...

```
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);  // here the query executed

if($row!=NULL)    // here checking row not equal to null value.
{

Displaying part...

}
else      // here if the row is NULL; it will print the following echo statement.
{
echo "Invalid input.";
}
```